# Unable to create Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to create an Azure 'Storage Account'. But when I'm checking on it, it was noted that the create button in invisible.

Can someone please help the issue here

[image]

[image]

### Error:

{"name":"3f798dea-c1e3-481f-8668-06affeb3006c","httpStatusCode":409,"headers":{"Pragma":"no-cache","x-ms-failure-cause":"gateway","x-ms-request-id":"86907243-3eb6-400e-84db-cfdef144dab9","x-ms-correlation-request-id":"90c50192-dc1a-4e4f-a136-1e1e91d44fda","x-ms-routing-request-id":"SOUTHEASTASIA:20221115T042659Z:86907243-3eb6-400e-84db-cfdef144dab9","Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains","X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Date":"Tue, 15 Nov 2022 04:26:58 GMT"},"content":{"error":{"code":"ReadOnlyDisabledSubscription","message":"The subscription '96440d8a-2081-4c3f-b032-6bf9da5138f2' is disabled and therefore marked as read only. You cannot perform any write actions on this subscription until it is re-enabled."}},"contentLength":246}

This is my first account and nothing I have done yet.
Shouldn't I get the free $200?

[image]

Comment: Click on Review, you should able to see create option once all options are valid in reveiw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete the Next Advanced Tab Options if you want to fill the Networking options, Encryption options, Security level options or Click on Review Tab for the default options, then you will be able to see the Create Option to create the storage account.

[image]

> Your free credit has expired. Upgrade to keep going with your account.

As it is clearly saying that the free credit is expired. So, upgrade to pay-as-you-go account. Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/avoid-charges-free-account) for more information on subscription credit expiry and upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ansewer. I have edited my answer. It give me a subscription error. Could you kindly please check again